# c# - What's the best way to keep log for events of windows form application?

Tags: c#, logging

Everytime users did something like add, delete or edit data.
I want to keep the record of it. So system admin can see who did what later.

For example

```
  private AddUser(User id)
    {
        if(id != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Item Updated");
            string sqlAddUser = "INSERT INTO 'DATABASE.USER' VALUES (Item.ID, Item.Name, Item.Address)";
            if(db.SqlNonQuery(sqlAddUser) //If successful
            {
                ///To DO : Add system log into database
                ///Ex. string sqlLog = DateTime.Now + User.ID + " added Item ID " + item.ID; 
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error");            
            }    
        }
    }
```

Is there any better way or common practice to do it? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general for logging, I recommend [Log4Net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/); it's highly configurable and works great.

However, if you don't want to invest the time in implementing a third-party component and wanted to log to the database, you could do your data access via stored procedure, and have an `INSERT` into a logging table as part of the SP.